# JavaScript button?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a button that adds on 0.00142 each time and I've created a simple JavaScript function but it doesn't seem to work?
Any help? Thanks! :)

```
<input type="button" value="Count" id="countButton" />

<p>You've burned <span id="displayCount">0</span> Calories!</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var count = +0.00142;
  var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
  var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

  button.onclick = function(){
    count++;
    display.innerHTML = count;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: <input type="button" value="Count" id="countButton" /> is at the top of the code

Comment: Java is not Javascript please be careful when adding the tags in your question.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry... fixed ;)

Comment: Maybe I'll like your site more if I can burn 1 Calories with one click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var total = 0;
  var count = 0.00142;
  var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
  var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

  button.onclick = function(){
    total = total + count;
    display.innerHTML = total;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ah I see thank you this was a really big bug for some reason!

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: Oh by the way... How using this would I be able to save the count information so that when a user comes back the count is still present? I know it is possible but i'm still in the learning of Java-Script and HTML so i'm not sure how I could go about doing it?

Comment: HTML is stateless, which means you'll either need to save it in a cookie or some sort of database.